# Fibonacci sequence using a do-while loop in java?

Tags: java, while-loop, sequence, fibonacci

I am trying to print a *Fibonacci* sequence using a `do-while` loop in java and can't understand this.  Needs to be between 0 and 100.

I have the following code:

```
int prevPrevVal = 0;
int prevVal = 1;
int currVal;
System.out.println(prevPrevVal);
System.out.println(prevVal);

do
{       
    currVal = prevVal + prevPrevVal;
    System.out.println(currVal);

    prevPrevVal = prevVal;
    prevVal = currVal;          
} while (prevVal <= 100);
```

Comment: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Fibonacci_series_with_do_while_in_java

Comment: You could have just *Googled* this.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3):

This is a simplified program to find out the Fibonacci series by providing the conditional limit in the while loop. Hope you guys get an idea over with this....!!

```
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    int temp=1;
    do {    
        a=b;
        b=temp;
        temp=a+b;
        System.out.println(temp);
    }while(temp<100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to do it with two variables and without printing a number out of range. Sorry if it's crappy, it's my first day of programming :)

```
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;

    do
    {
        System.out.println(x);
        y = x + y;
        if (y < 100)
        {
            System.out.println(y);
        }
        x = x + y;
    } while (x < 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be your solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     int prevVal = 1;
     int prevPrevVal = 0;
     int n = 0;
     do{
         int currVal = prevVal + prevPrevVal;
         prevPrevVal = prevVal;
         prevVal = currVal;
         System.out.print(currVal+" ");
         n++;
     }while(n<5);//n is the number of terms


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
int prevVal = 1;
int prevPrevVal = 0;
        do{
        int currVal = prevVal + prevPrevVal;
                    //currVal is your Fibonacc seq.
        prevPrevVal = prevVal;
        prevVal = currVal;
    }
    while(yourCondition);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the basic structure of a `do-while` loop from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html):

```
do {
    statement(s)
} while (expression);
```

What you want in the "statement(s)" section is to increment (and possibly output) your result through each iteration. A basic Fibonacci sequence using a `do-while` loop would look like the following:

```
int prevVal = 1;
int prevPrevVal = 0;
int currVal;
do {
    // Add the two numbers
    currVal = prevVal + prevPrevVal;
    // "Bump" up prevPrevVal to prevVal, and prevVal to currVal
    prevPrevVal = prevVal;
    prevVal = currVal;
    // Output to the screen
    System.out.println(currval + "\n");
} while(expression);
```

Comment: I added the code I got, but it prints up to 144. Is there a reason?

Comment: Your conditional says `prevVal <= 100`. In this case, that's telling the `do-while` loop to execute until `prevVal` exceeds or equals 100--this means that `prevVal` and `prevPrevVal` will stop with values of 89 and 55, respectively. In the next iteration, `prevVal` will be equal to `currVal`, which is 144, and since that's greater than 100, the loop terminates.

Comment: I need to print 0 - 100. I can't get that to happen.

Comment: If you mean you need to print out 100 iterations of the Fibonacci sequence, you should take a look at @Dibya 's answer/solution, although it's for 5 iterations and can be easily modified to 100. :)

Comment: AHHH I see. I fixed it now. It is supposed to hit 89. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the terms of Fibonacci up to 100,just change `while (prevVal <= 100);` to `while (prevVal+prevPrevVal <= 100);`

This will print up to 89.